# Google Data Studio export to PDF and scheduled email

Tags: pdf, scheduled-tasks, looker-studio

I am looking for a way to automate the process of exporting Google Data Studio report pages in PDF, save them on cloud account (eg. OneDrive) and then email the saved PDF report on a monthly basis. This Chrome plug-in will only export the report in PDF, so I was looking for a way to automate this using MS Flow option. So I am wondering if anyone has tried to develop a flow with these steps in mind:

1. Open the report URL in Google Data Studio with a particular date range;
2. Use the Chrome plug-in to export the report pages in a single PDF;
3. Save the report on a cloud solution (eg. OneDrive);
4. Schedule an email that will attach the PDF and send it to couple of email addresses.

Hopefully someone has tried creating this flow and/or could shed some light on this issue. Note, that the plugin devs replied that they won't be adding this feature anytime soon due to privacy concerns (they will need to include a server-side option to save the reports).

Comment: I'm curious about why you want to email the PDF. Why not just share the link to the Data Studio dashboard?

Comment: Good question. I guess it is a combination of client habit and convenience. Sharing the link is OK, but the biggest problem is that they need to login to google account. Another problem is the date range and the need to tell them to adjust the range, an option here would be to somehow "fix" the date range when sending out a monthly report. Sometimes report needs to be shared to upper ladders and PDFs are more convenient in that matter because the dates are fixed. That's to name a few.

Comment: Another minor inconvenience is not having the option to schedule emails, although email clients are a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the new [email delivery schedule](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9263641) feature. See the [release notes](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6311467) for the announcement.

Answer (score 1):

[Scheduled Emails along with a PDF](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9263641) can be achieved by clicking on the `Share` drop down on the top right of the report and selecting `Schedule email delivery`.

A scheduled time can be selected as well as selecting a repeat option; in addition a customised email subject and message can also be sent.

Once done hit schedule and the selected user(s) will receive a PDF of the report as well as a link to the respective report.

Once created, the scheduled email delivery could be edited, or deleted if required.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/8f6301fc-ae59-44b6-ae09-3f3ee03dd669) and GIF to elaborate:

[image]